# Why does C++ allow making a reference to a variable that goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following code

```
struct Ri {
    int& i;
};

auto do_something() {
    int v{2};
    return Ri{v};
}
```

Why is this allowed to compile?

It should be possible to infer that the scope of the returned `Ri` object is that of the caller. Why is it allowed to be created with a reference to a variable with the local scope?

Is there a legitimate use case for this?

Comment: Not an answer, but it sounds like you want to be learning [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org).

Comment: There's no legitimate usecase, and sometimes compilers warn about this (not in this case for some reason, though). Mandatory error here sounds hard to implement in general. (Without a radical rust-like solution.)

Comment: Speed. As a rule, the more managed the language is, the slower it runs.

Comment: Or the slower the compiler runs, @Galik

Comment: C++ relies *heavily* on the programmer knowing *all* the language rules and *not* making any mistakes. It gains a lot of speed from this, by not having to check whether something you wrote makes sense. But, the language and tool-chain is not going to hold your hand (it may *try* sometimes, but don't depend on it). See for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub (including the linked articles). Basically; if it is semantically valid it will compile. Whether it makes sense or not, or follows the rules, that's for *you* to know if you want to avoid UB.

Comment: Grab the g++ sourcecode, and add a warning for this yourself. Just because something is immediately obvious to us doesn't mean the compiler will just spot it as well -- and C++ does not mandate such a diagnostic. C++, as a language, allows many mistakes to be made.

Comment: It's based off C, which assumes you know exactly what you're doing, perhaps? :)

Comment: There is almost nothing in C++ that isn't allowed to compile. A `#error` directive is the only thing that comes to mind; when it's triggered, compilation ends. Aside from that, the C++ standard doesn't distinguish "warning", "error", or whatever. When a requirement (but not one that's specified with "no diagnostic required") is not met the compiler must **issue a diagnostic**. Having done that, it's free to continue compiling the code, with an implementation-specific meaning. That's the primary hook for implementation-specific extensions.

Comment: The question got answered in comments, thanks. I don't immediatly see why implementing this would be so expensive, either for the compiled program or in terms of the compilation time. The compiler would have to take note of scope of each object, and upon creating a refeference it should check that the reference doesn't have a broader scope than the referenced object. Should be O(N), unless Im missing something. Learning Rust is an option, I keed hearing good things about it.

Comment: Rhetorical question: how would you write the rule that eliminates this issue? There are lots of ways to create a reference that outlives the object that it refers to, many of them far more subtle than this one. The standard doesn't, in general, impose requirements for simple versions of coding errors while leaving more subtle variations alone. Instead, it tends to use the catchall that the behavior of a program that does X is undefined. That leaves it up to the implementation to decide what's worth diagnosing and what isn't.

Comment: C++ is so flexible that it is **impossible** to implement. Yes, simple cases like your code above can be detected, and probably should give a warning. But in general, it is not possible. For example the existance of conversions between pointers and numerical values, and pointer arithmetic, already makes it impossible for a compiler to always know whether reference is valid or not.

Comment: @PeteBecker do you have specific subtle cases in mind? Every object does have a scope, so checking the scope of a reference and the references object does not seem very complicated, at the face of it.

Comment: @user23952 Think about dynamically allocated objects, global objects, custom allocators and placement new, `reinterpret_cast`, `std::launder`, `volatile` and much more, and it becomes *really hard* in some cases to reason about whether an objects life time has ended or not.

Comment: @user23952 -- I don't have a particular example in mind, but here's something off the top of my head: `Ri f(bool use, int&i) { int j = 3; return make_me_an_Ri(use, i, j); }`, with `Ri make_me_an_Ri(bool, int& i, int&j) { return Ri(use ? i : j); }`. Contrived, I know, but depending on the value of `use` there may or may not be a reference to a local object.

Comment: @user23952 here is one example: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/MoqbY8as9). In this case `v` goes out of scope, but `g` that is references is still in scope. Should this be valid? I think so. But now the compiler has to keep track of "assigned" scope. This can quickly escalate to a large mess.

Comment: @user23952 -- now imagine that `make_me_an_Ri` is defined in a separate translation unit (think "source file") than the rest of the code. The bookkeeping to diagnose this sort of thing becomes very expensive. The C++ standard opted to spend compiler resources on other things.

Comment: Another example: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/daxhrzo6G). The compiler has no way of figuring out lifetime of the ref returned by `get_v()`.

Comment: I see there are many diffrent aspects to think about, but let's try: in @Super-intelligentShade's examples (thanks for writing it clearly on GodBolt), it is the scope of objects that should be considered, not the scope of references. So in case https://godbolt.org/z/daxhrzo6G, the scope of object refrerenced by `int& v` is still that of the translation unit. I don't see how ```reinterpret_cast``` would chage the scope of the object, the scope of the returned object should be the same as that of the input, shouldn't it?

Comment: The answer is *mu* (unask the question).  The real question is:  Why does user23952 allow making a reference to a variable that goes out of scope in C++ which is an ill-formed no-diagnostic-required invalid program?

Comment: @user23952 things can escalate really fast, even with simple examples: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/8GGT44aTM).

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade, yes, in this example, the lifetime of the object is not known. I think your example applies to any use of dynamic allocation, as an object could be deleted in by an external call, or some other convoluted manner.

Comment: Because it isn’t an error. *Returning* it could be an error, but that’s not what you asked about. There’s nothing wrong with using such a reference inside the same scope.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a reason why this is allowed to compile?

Because there is nothing in the standard that says it shouldn't.

> Surely it is possible to infer that the scope of the returned Ri object is that of the caller. So why is it allowed to be created with a reference to a variable with the local scope?

In this particular case, yes. But in general things may not be so simple.

Here is one example:

```cpp
int g = 42;

struct Ri { int& i; };

auto do_something()
{
    int& v = g;
    return Ri{v};
}
```

What should the compiler do in this case? `v` went out of scope, but `g` that it referred to is still in scope. So, now the compiler has to keep track of the scope of the assigned value? Multiply number of variables by number of assignments and things may start getting a bit hairy.

Here is another example:

```cpp
extern int& get_v(); // external library with no source code

struct Ri { int& i; };

auto do_something()
{
    int& v = get_v();
    return Ri{v};
}
```

In this case the compiler has no way of knowing lifetime of the value returned by `get_v()`. So, what do we do now?

**UPDATE**:

You/compiler can't assume that the scope of the value returned by `get_v()` extends to the translation unit, eg:

```cpp
extern void init();   // create value returned by get_v()
extern int& get_v();  // return value
extern void deinit(); // delete value returned by get_v()

struct Ri { int& i; };

auto do_something()
{
    init();
    int& v = get_v();
    deinit();
    return Ri{v};
}
```

> Is there a legitimate use case for this?

I don't think so.

Comment: Well observed and described. The first example can be addressed. As I suggested in the comments, we are  considering for this purpose the scope of objects, not of references. The scope of the object referenced to by `v` is the translation unit.  In the second example, I agree, the lifetime of the object is not knowable from the availalbe source code. The function `get_v()` could modify or delete the returned object on a different thread for all we know. It does not invalidate that this lifetime check can be performed in many realistic cases.

Comment: @user23952 -- translation units do not define scopes. The value referenced by `v` is `g`, and it's a **global** object; it lives in global scope.

Comment: The scope of the object referernced by `v` is defined by `get_v()`. In [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/Md95KWPzj), the scope of `v` is the `get_v()` function, so it is dead on arrival. Of course, no way for the compiler to know that, so there is no way to detect the error in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is allowed to compile is because the C++ standard says it compiles.

You are right that this always returns a dangling reference. So does the much simpler:

```cpp
int& do_something() {
    int v = 2;
    return v;
}
```

There are some cases where dangling references are explicitly disallowed. One is in a mem-initializer:

```cpp
struct Ri {
    Ri() : i(2) {}  // Error: Cannot have reference bind to a temporary
    const int& i = 2;
};
```

The other is with `INVOKE<R>`:

```cpp
int f();
std::function<const int&()> g = f;  // Error: Returned reference would bind to a temporary and immediately dangle
```

These are both for references that become dangling because of temporaries that immediately die.

Noone has put in the effort to make your specific example ill-formed. Someone would have to write a paper and submit it to the C++ standards committee.

But it is likely to be rejected because it would be too much effort to verify and standardise and implementations should already give you warnings about the dangling reference without making it flat out ill-formed.

---

As for a "legitimate" reason: Comparing `&do_something().i` with a pointer to any previously created `int` object would have to compare unequal. E.g.:

```cpp
extern Ri x;
extern int i;
assert(&do_something().i != &x.i);
assert(&do_something().i != &i);
assert(&do_something().i != nullptr);
```

If your type was something hard to access, this dangling reference can give you something of the correct type that can actually be used (as opposed to `std::declval`):

```cpp
struct Rnp {
    std::nullptr_t& np;
};

struct Empty {};

struct Re {
    Empty& e;
};

constexpr Rnp get_np() { std::nullptr_t np; return Rnp{ np }; }
constexpr Re get_e() { Empty e; return Re{ e }; }

static_assert(get_np().np == 0);
static_assert([]{
    Re re = get_e();
    return typeid(re.e) == typeid(Empty);
}());
```

Or maybe it comes from a code path that isn't actually ran:

```cpp
template<typename U>
U f(auto&& fn) {
    auto x = fn();
    return U{x};
}

[[noreturn]] int die();

int main() {
    f<Ri>(die);  // It might be much more subtle in an actual codebase
}
```

These are pretty contrived reasons, but remember the ultimate reason it compiles is because the standard doesn't say it isn't allowed.

In fact, these contrived reasons can also be applied to mem-initializers and `INVOKE<R>`, but the committee voted that disallowing these constructs is more useful than harmful.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed because there is nothing wrong in your code. If you were to access the reference you would invoke undefined behavior, but you are not doing that. Compilers will try to warn about that.

For example this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Ri {
    int& i;
};

auto do_something() {
    int v{2};
    return Ri{v};
}

int main() {
    auto x = do_something();
    std::cout << x.i;
}
```

[gcc produces following output (`-Werror -Wall -O3`)](https://godbolt.org/z/M5v55sPcf):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:14:20: error: 'v' is used uninitialized [-Werror=uninitialized]
   14 |     std::cout << x.i;
      |                    ^
<source>:8:9: note: 'v' was declared here
    8 |     int v{2};
      |         ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

However, it will not warn when you remove `-O3`. It will also not warn when you remove the line that attempts to print the value of `x.i`.